# VHDL process causes errors

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, vhdl, synchronous

I'm new to VHDL so I just have a question to ask about why this produces an error. I have an ALU defined in VHDL:

```
c <=        a + b       WHEN opc="0111"
ELSE        a - b       WHEN opc="1000"
ELSE        -a          WHEN opc="1011"
ELSE        -b          WHEN opc="0001"
ELSE        ABS(a)      WHEN opc="1110"
ELSE        ABS (b)     WHEN opc="1010"
ELSE        NOT a       WHEN opc="0010"
ELSE        NOT b       WHEN opc="1100"
ELSE        a AND b     WHEN opc="0100"
ELSE        a OR b      WHEN opc="0110"
ELSE        a XOR b     WHEN opc="0101"
```

(this is the architecture)

But then I want to make it synchronous,

```
PROCESS (clock)
BEGIN
    IF(rising_edge(clock)) THEN
        c <=        a + b       WHEN opc="0101"
        ELSE        a - b       WHEN opc="1000"
        ELSE        -a          WHEN opc="1011"
        ELSE        -b          WHEN opc="0001"
        ELSE        ABS(a)      WHEN opc="1110"
        ELSE        ABS (b)     WHEN opc="1010"
        ELSE        NOT a       WHEN opc="0010"
        ELSE        NOT b       WHEN opc="1100"
        ELSE        a AND b     WHEN opc="0100"
        ELSE        a OR b      WHEN opc="0110"
        ELSE        a XOR b     WHEN opc="0111" 
    END IF
END PROCESS;
```

This doesn't work, it comes up with various errors like:

```
';' expected.
Keyword "end" expected.
```

So I have now changed my code to:

```
PROCESS (clock)
BEGIN
    IF(rising_edge(clock)) THEN 
        CASE opc IS
            WHEN "0101" => c <= a+b;       
            WHEN "1000" => c <= a-b;      
            WHEN "1011" => c <= -a;   
            WHEN "0001" => c <= -b;   
            WHEN "1110" => c <= ABS(a);  
            WHEN "1010" => c <= ABS(b); 
            WHEN "0010" => c <= NOT a;   
            WHEN "1100" => c <= NOT b;  
            WHEN "0100" => c <= a AND b;  
            WHEN "0110" => c <= a OR b;  
            WHEN "0111" => c <= a XOR b; 
        END CASE; 
    END IF; 
END PROCESS;
```

And this doesn't produce any errors. But why does the original code which worked when put in a process not work unless I use the case statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ternary operator `c <= a when condition else b;` is not allowed inside of process statements prior to VHDL-2008. SO you can enable VHDL-2008 support if your tool supports this or you use your later code example, which is much nicer :)

Comment: Paebbels is correct, and I have to add that if you are designing for ASIC or FPGA (specially) you should avoid nested If-Then-Elest statement. Also, at the end of your process add the "others" to make sure all the cases are covered with that statement.

Comment: Nitpick: conditional assignment is not exactly a "ternary operator", though it functions like one in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In order of effort:

- If you have access to VHDL 2008 in your tools, enable it.  If not, bug the vendor to support it!
- add an extra signal calling `c_sync` and then add a line:

  `c_sync <= c when rising_edge(clk);`
- Change your code to a set of `if then` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Your first try to make it synchronous didn't work because:

- You haven't enabled *VHDL 2008* (as stated in the other answers/comments)
- the end of the conditional assignment is missing a `;`
- your `END IF` is missing a `;`

---

Your second try works, because it doesn't require *VHDL 2008*:

The `case`-statement has been supported in processes since the first VHDL version, while the conditional assignment was previously forbidden inside processes (which has been changed with *VHDL 2008*).